# Supernova impact on Protostar formation

Tags: astrophysics, star-formation, protostar

What would be the impact on the formation of a new star (protostar) when a nearby star (within 10 LY) goes supernova? Will the force of the explosion (once it arrives in the Molecular Cloud where the star is forming) disrupt the process to the point where the new star cannot complete the 10-million-year process to form a solar-type star?

Comment: Didn’t you get that it greatly depends on *stage* when the forming protostar was disrupted?